# Как загружать изображения по порядку?

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Привет) при загрузке изображений формируется массив, но отображается он почему то рандомно, что-не так? вот код и скрин:

```js
var uploadImages = (function () {

    function uploadImages(uploadBtn, outputImages) {

        var btn = document.getElementById(uploadBtn),
            output = document.getElementById(outputImages),
            testInput = document.getElementsByName('testUpload')[0],
            file,
            i,
            iImage;

    
        var maxArr = [];

        function handleUpload(evt) {
            iImage = evt.target.files;

            for (i = 0; i < iImage.length; i++) {
                file = iImage[i];

                 console.log(file);
                //   uploadArray = unique(uploadArray);


                var fileReviu = new FileReader();

                fileReviu.onload = (function (iFile) {
                    return function (e) {
                        if (document.getElementById(escape(iFile.name)) == null){
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        // div.id = escape(iFile.name);
                        div.innerHTML = ['<img class="img-thumbnail" ', ' src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(iFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        // console.log(div.innerHTML);
                        document.getElementById('outputMulti').insertBefore(div, null);
                      }
                    }
                })(file);

                fileReviu.readAsDataURL(file);

        }

        }

        btn.addEventListener('change', handleUpload, false);
    }
    return uploadImages;
})();


uploadImages('fileMulti', 'outputMulti');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testComponents</title>
  <!--meta-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="Copyright" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <!--css-->

  <style>
    .img-thumbnail {
      height: 75px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <label>Мультизагрузка файлов:</label>
      <input type="hiden" id="testUpload" name="testUpload" value="666">
      <input type="file" id="fileMulti" name="fileMulti[]" multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span id="outputMulti"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

[image: неверное отображение img]

Смотреть на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfn9qwtz/68/)

Comment: Собственно, никакой проблемы не обнаружил... 
http://prntscr.com/isgfb6

Comment: От нечего делать переименовал картинки как у вас чтоб было.. Результат остался прежним - всё в норме. Почистите кеш, куки в браузере

Answer (score 0):

Ну да. Имена файлов вы читаете по порядку и записываете их в консоль. А потом сразу ставите файлы на загрузку и не дожидаясь ее окончания обрабатываете остальные файлы. Ну так какой файл быстрее загрузится тот первым в превью и добавиться. Можно сделать так. Сразу создаём div под картинки. Для картинок в функцию загрузки передаем ещё и созданный Div куда эту картинку потом отобразить. Теперь они будут по порядку. Только вот порядок определяет ОС и он как правило алфавитный, а не тот в котором вы выделяли файлы. По хорошему нужно делать еще ручную сортировку после загрузки, например с помощью drag and drop.

```js
var uploadImages = (function () {

    function uploadImages(uploadBtn, outputImages) {

        var btn = document.getElementById(uploadBtn),
            output = document.getElementById(outputImages),
            testInput = document.getElementsByName('testUpload')[0],
            file,
            i,
            iImage;

    
        var maxArr = [];

        function handleUpload(evt) {
            iImage = evt.target.files;

            for (i = 0; i < iImage.length; i++) {
                file = iImage[i];

                 console.log(file);
                //   uploadArray = unique(uploadArray);
                var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                // div.id = escape(iFile.name);
                // div.innerHTML = ['<img class="img-thumbnail" ', ' src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(iFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('outputMulti').insertBefore(newdiv, null);


                var fileReviu = new FileReader();

                fileReviu.onload = (function (iFile,iFileDiv) {
                    return function (e) {
                        //if (document.getElementById(escape(iFile.name)) == null){
                        //var div = document.createElement('div');
                        // div.id = escape(iFile.name);
                        iFileDiv.innerHTML = ['<img class="img-thumbnail" ', ' src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(iFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                        // console.log(div.innerHTML);
                        //document.getElementById('outputMulti').insertBefore(div, null);
                        //}
                    }
                })(file, newdiv);

                fileReviu.readAsDataURL(file,newdiv);

            }

        }

        btn.addEventListener('change', handleUpload, false);
    }
    return uploadImages;
})();


uploadImages('fileMulti', 'outputMulti');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>testComponents</title>
  <!--meta-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="Copyright" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <!--css-->

  <style>
    .img-thumbnail {
      height: 75px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <label>Мультизагрузка файлов:</label>
      <input type="hiden" id="testUpload" name="testUpload" value="666">
      <input type="file" id="fileMulti" name="fileMulti[]" multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span id="outputMulti"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```